# What does ls -d command stand for in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

When i type **ls -l -d** in my terminal and the current working directory in **root** then it show

```
root@devils-ey3:~# ls -l -d
drwxrwxr-x 57 root root 4096 Apr 30 11:16 .
```

But when i was in other current directory assume that it was **/usr/** or **/usr/bin/** then the output is also same as before just change a few thing like filesize,id,date.

```
root@devils-ey3:/usr/bin# ls -l -d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 118784 Apr 29 23:10 .
```

I read the document of ls -d. It write

```
-d, --directory            list directory entries instead of contents,
                               and do not dereference symbolic links
```

I am confused that why we used ls -d and why it shows most likely same outputs in every different directory ?

Comment: Try specifying a directory as an argument, e.g. `ls /` vs `ls -d /`. Or even several directories, e.g. `ls / /bin/ /etc/` vs `ls -d / /bin/ /etc/`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and more suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before you close it, I want to know what distro he is using so I can avoid it. Any distro with a broken `man page` install is something I want to stay away from... Seriously, the only pain with `-d` is **it doesn't do what you want it to**. Well, that's just because you are not using it correctly. As the answers have shown, you must tell it to find subdirectories and not the present directory (boring result). So to find subs: `ls -d /*`

Answer (score 4):

In Linux (or generally, UNIX-like systems), all directories contain the entries:

- `.` is the relative reference to the *current* directory
- `..` is the relative reference to the *parent* directory

Since you're adding the `-d` flag, it'll list the directory itself, not its content. See `ls --help`:

> `-d` list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

Comment: Actually it's `-a` that shows hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` switch essentially says “I am interested in the directory itself, not its contents”. See:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ ls -l foo # show me detailed info about the contents of “foo”
-rw-r--r--  1 zoul  staff     0B Apr 30 10:20 bar
$ ls -ld foo # show me detailed info about “foo” itself
drwxr-xr-x  3 zoul  staff   102B Apr 30 10:20 foo
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says: `list directory entries instead of contents,`.

If you have `subdirectories` it will only shows the name of the sub directory and not all the files in the subdirectory.
And also links will not followed. So you ony see the entries in the directory you called ls -d.